# Clean/reduce static in electret microphone caused by "dirty" Raspberry Pi pin output voltage

Tags: dc, raspberry-pi, ground

I'm currently trying to wire up an electret microphone to a Raspberry Pi. I just figured out how to wire it up to a button cell battery after a couple of days of struggling. Still learning electronics so bear with me.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNouIo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want to remove the button cell, and replace it with the +3.3V to GRND pins on the Raspberry Pi 3B+, but the problem I'm encountering is when connecting ground to the ground pin on the Pi, I get a lot of audible static in my voice recordings.

I'm assuming that this is because the ground pin isn't limited to -3.3V like with my button cell.

**Is there a way to limit the negative voltage potential of the ground pin?**

My instincts tell me that using a capacitor can accomplish this somehow, but I'm not sure of the approach.

Comment: Where on the Rpi you intend to connect that?

Comment: *I get a lot of static* - is that static electricity or static noise as you hear on an FM radio?

Comment: @Justme, I was hoping to use the +3.3V pin, and Ground

Comment: @Andyaka Static noise like on the radio

Comment: You probably need to explain where the speaker is connected and precisely which pins of the RaPi you are connecting your microphone to.

Comment: Ground is zero volts by definition, I'm not sure what you're talking about here. This sounds like a ground loop problem.

Comment: @Hearth can you explain what you mean by a ground loop problem? I fear that I am seriously misunderstanding something. Should I just be able to replace the 3.3V button cell battery with the 3.3-GRND pin combination on my Pi?

Comment: @Andyaka I've updated the post to reflect this but, tl;dr - I am replacing the hot and ground of the button cell to the +3.3V and ground pins on the Pi

Comment: You should, yes. But you'll need to explain more about what's going on here so we can see if there's a ground loop, which causes circuits to pick up lots of noise. It's a common problem in audio circuits.

Comment: @Hearth Tip and Ring are connected to a 4 pole aux cord (via screw terminal block) plugged into my smart phone for testing + an audio recording app. This is all hooked up to a breadboard, including a microphone -- not sure if that is causing any static interference. Using the button cell, everything sounds great, but when swapping out the battery for the +3.3V to GRND pins on the Pi, I get that static interference.

What other information can help you?

Comment: Is your smartphone plugged into a charger? What's the power source for the rpi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on KD9PDP's answer.

If the 3.3V from the RPi is noisy, you can improve the filter by adding a series resistor, electret mics don't draw much current. You may need to experiment with the resistor values.

If you have noise on the ground wires, that is harder to fix. If you can float your RPi, connect the mic circuit ground to one point at the RPi.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQEFeq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The first step in eliminating noise is to identify the source. I think you did a good identifying the noise source in this example. If the static does not exist when you use the battery but does exist when you you the Pi's +3.3V and ground, then the noise is from the Pi's power pins (which is pretty common). Think about it as noise on both the + and - supply, not just the ground. You want DC,  but are getting DC plus lots of static noise, so you can get rid of that by putting a capacitor from the positive voltage supply to ground. A common thing your see people do is put a 10 uF in parallel to a 100 nF between V+ and ground to take advantage of specific non-ideal capacitor behavior.

That should help clean up your supply voltage. Something else to look into is the problem is still there is an audio transformer. That will isolate the ground of the Pi from the ground of the audio input. That helps if there is a "ground loop" that acts like a radio antenna. However, that noise usually sounds like a hum, not static.

Edit: in above, every time I say "ground" I mean the negative supply or ground - they are the same thing in my description above.

Comment: Ah... dirty voltage is something I hadn't considered. I naively assumed the pi would put out the DC power it was rated for. I'll try your suggestion of using a larger capacitor in parallel to clean the DC voltage coming in.